# How to add content to tab items at runtime in WPF

Tags: wpf

How can I add a Web Browser control to a tabItem in WPF at runtime?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
tabItem.Content = new WebBrowser();
```

If you want multiple controls in the TabItem, you'll need to use a `Panel`, just like you would in XAML.